# Preview Cursor files in Nautilus

Tags: 22.04, nautilus

currently there is no way to see how a cursor file looks like in Nautilus. It is listed using dummy icons as seen below. Is there any plugin or other means to enable preview of these cursor files? Thanks.

PS: Using Ubuntu 22.04

[image]

Comment: If you don't have file extensions that it won't render any thumbnails

Comment: It doesn't, even with the corresponding extensions in 22.04.

Comment: What is `mimetype FILE_NAME` and `gio mime TYPE/NAME`? replace FILE_NAME with one of these files and TYPE/NAME with the type that comes out of the first command.